# Docker compose network to access virtual machine on lan

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have some virtual development machines on my lan that i use for testing out openvidu developments, the main server in question sits on 192.168.1.0/24 with ip 192.168.1.150.

I want my local docker development environment via docker compose to be able to access this ip address, so i've setup a bridge network:

```
networks:
  my-net:
    name: my-net
  my-lan-access:
    name: my-lan-access
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.1.0/24"
        - gateway: "192.168.1.254"
```

Then i allow the specific containers access to this network:

```
networks:
      my-net:
      my-lan-access:
        ipv4_address: "192.168.1.149"
```

I logged into one of the containers and attempted to ping 192.168.1.150 and i get:

```
From 192.168.1.149 icmp_seq=160 Destination Host Unreachable
```

It's clearly added the correct network as it's got 192.168.1.149 ip address yet it's unable to see the virtual machine.

Note: From outside the container on my mac i can ping 192.168.1.150 no problem and access via ssh.

**UPDATE**

After some reading i get why this doesn't work, it's because the bridge adapter doesn't exist on my host machine.

The idea isn't to spend time creating a bridge adapter, if the compose file needs to be sent to another developer we want to just be able to fire it all up without any hassle.

So i started to look at "macvlan" which seems like a much better option where by i can connect my specific containers directly to the lan from the host adapter:

```
networks:
  my-net:
    name: my-net
  my-lan-access:
    name: my-lan-access
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: en0
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "192.168.1.0/24"
          gateway: "192.168.1.254"
```

This now brings up a new error though:

```
ERROR: invalid subinterface vlan name en0, example formatting is eth0.10

This doesn't make any sense, i can clearly see the en0 interface (my wifi adapter) on my mac with ifconfig:

en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
        ether b0:f1:d8:21:22:dd 
        inet6 fe80::1400:ad93:eea1:2818%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xe 
        inet 192.168.1.124 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:10a5:3e52:179e:aa31 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
        inet6 2a00:23c5:ef15:1101:45d:dabb:8af:43a3 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
        inet6 2a00:23c5:ef15:1101:419:9097:a2b3:5cf7 prefixlen 64 deprecated autoconf temporary 
        inet6 2a00:23c5:ef15:1101:edd5:a0e0:baa1:b3ae prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active
```

So instead i tried en0.0 hoping it would understand i don't have a sub adapter which causes this error:

**ERROR: -o parent interface does was not found on the host: en0**

It appears like this might be a bug in docker or docker compose?

So maybe the only option i have is to create my own bridge adapter attached to my hardware interface?

Comment: I would expect you can access the machines on the host's network by IP address with the default configuration.  The `my-lan-access` network will probably actually prevent you from accessing it; I might delete all of the `networks:` you show here.

Comment: But i need the "my-net" otherwise the containers won't talk to each other right?

Comment: Tried what you said and it still doesn't work

Comment: My suspicion is, if you delete every `networks:` block in the entire file, things will work fine.  (Compose creates a network named `default` for inter-container communication, and you do not need to create one yourself; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.)  The `eth0`/`en0` difference is because Docker Desktop on MacOS runs a hidden Linux VM, and that might also make the `macvlan` driver tricky to set up.